# CCsprite.flipX not working!

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Here is my function, it makes random point on the ground and makes my sprite go there. If the x position of location is less then position of my sprite, I flip my sprite so it looked left (it looks right by default). But this is not working at all. I tried different flip methods but none work! 
Please help what is wrong?

```
- (void) wander
{
    CGPoint rand = CGPointMake(CCRANDOM_0_1() * 270 , CCRANDOM_0_1() * 140 );

    float distance = ccpDistance([currentSprite position], rand);
    float speed = distance / 2;
    ccTime time = distance / speed;
    CCAction *move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:time position:rand];

    if (currentSprite.position.x > rand.x)
    {

       currentSprite.flipX = YES;
    }
    else {
        currentSprite.flipX = NO;
    }

    [self runAction:move];
}
```

There is no problem with this code. Problem was that I was trying to flip sprite that was a child of my Pet object. When I tried flipping sprite everything worked just fine. If anybody could explain that, would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try flipping it by using the scale:

```
currentSprite.scaleX *= -1.f;
```

You should also ensure that `currentSprite` is the sprite that contains the texture you want to flip, and is not a parent of the sprite that contains the texture you want to flip. See [the documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite.html#a8b3b3793750b2ffadfd4764da13f5a21) about `flipX` for more info.

Comment: I think the problem is in another method, can you please check out this question http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/what-is-the-correct-way-of-changing-image-of-existing-ccsprite

Comment: Have you tried the scale method?

Comment: Yes, didn't help.

Comment: Actually I have found the problem. I have composite class, Pet that contains sprite as property. I tried flipping that sprite and that didnt work. When I tried to flip pet it work. Can you please explain that behavior? Thank you for quick responce anyway.

Comment: I cannot explain that. If I'm reading correctly, it seems contrary to the documentation. Glad you were able to solve it.